# AGPL-compatible license

Tags: java, licensing, gpl, legal, bsd-license

I am using a java library licensed under AGPL3. 
However, I would like to license my own work as BSD, such that my code could then be integrated in proprietary projects if one strips the library. Will I be allowed to do that?

So far, I couldn't find a clear answer for my problem on the net or in the license text(not a lawyer). Dual-licensing seems cumbersome and ugly.

EDIT: What happens if I use other libraries which are licensed under BSD or anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quote from the Licensing section of the GNU website:

> It has always been the FSF's position
>   that dynamically linking applications
>   to libraries creates a single work
>   derived from both the library code and
>   the application code. The GPL requires
>   that all derivative works be licensed
>   under the GPL, an effect which can be
>   described as “hereditary.” So, if an
>   application links to a library
>   licensed under the GPL, the
>   application too must be licensed under
>   the GPL.

*(the [specific page](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-java.html) is discussing Java and LGPL, but the general point applies here)*

**If you want to license your original application as BSD, you must first create it *without* using that library at all.**

Then, you can create a derivative work by combining your BSD application and the AGPL3 library, with the whole thing licensed as AGPL3.

This would effectively be a new, different application, and is not dual-licensing.

Since you want your BSD application to be used commercially, you would need to release it separately from the extended AGPL3 version of the application - which means two distinct links on your download page, with a clear explanation on the difference.

(NOTE: Anywhere I use "BSD" in this answer, it's important to note this refers to the "[modified BSD](http://www.xfree86.org/3.3.6/COPYRIGHT2.html#5)" *not* the [original BSD](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#OriginalBSD).)

> What happens if I use other libraries which are licensed under BSD or anything else?

That's fine. So long as the license allows for the code to be re-released under a compatible license and the AGPLv3 is considered compatible (which the BSD is - [see a full list here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses)), then you've got no problem.

If you plan on using lots of libraries/etc then it's a good idea to maintain a distinct credits file, where you can list each specific component you use, its website address, licensing requirements, and so on.

*(usual disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, follow at own risk, etc)*

Comment: Hmm, that's what I actually meant with dual-licensing. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: @Dan Cirnat: Do consult an attorney before you do this.

Comment: Dual licensing is a little different - it's releasing the exact *same code* under different licenses, not because any of the licenses require you to, but because you want to make it easier for others to use the code.

Comment: What happens if I use other libraries which are licensed under BSD or anything else? (also edited this into the initial question)

Comment: I am a student and can't afford a lawyer at the moment. :)

Comment: Dan, I've updated the answer - in short, that's fine.

Comment: Also, whilst getting real legal advice is of course sensible, I've never heard of someone having a licensing violation and immediately being prosecuted or whatever - since it generally is a case of a simple mistake being made, which is pointed out so that it can be corrected. (I guess this particularly would be the case for a student vs a commercial entity.)